# Angularjs url is being changed when using $http.get().then()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I have the following code:

1. First I log the url and I get desired url: `variants/images/30808708?ssl=true`

   ```
   var myUrl = self.baseUrl + 'images/' + self.currentItem.variants[variant].imageId + '?ssl=true'
   console.log(myUrl);  //prints: variants/images/30808708?ssl=true
   ```
2. Second I make the `http.get(myUrl).then(...)` call:

   ```
   $http.get(myUrl)
   .then(function(data) {
     //do something...
   }, function(e) {
     console.log('err', e); //error prints undefined
   });
   ```

   In the second piece of code it seems that the url is being double/tripled at the beginning like this:

`GET http://localhost:8080/variants/199variants/variants/images/30808708?ssl=true 404 (Not Found)`

Notice the `variants/199variants/variants/`

I'm not aware of where this repetition is coming from. Recently I update the app from 1.3 to 1.5, and removed the hashbang `#`due to some canonicalUrl error I was getting before. Not sure if this is relevant

This are the errors I get in console:

```
vendor.min.js:119 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Cc (vendor.min.js:16)
    at gc (vendor.min.js:93)
    at vendor.min.js:94
    at q (vendor.min.js:7)
    at md (vendor.min.js:94)
    at f (vendor.min.js:96)
    at vendor.min.js:132
    at m.$eval (vendor.min.js:147)
    at m.$digest (vendor.min.js:144)
(anonymous) @ vendor.min.js:119
vendor.min.js:119 Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:
 https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/pull/50
```

## Update

I tracked the first error stacktrace and it seems that sometimes backend returns html when data not found, and it passes the typeof === string of the following call:
[image]

D(a) is:

[image]

so it seems the error is cause at JSON.parse('

Comment: check your server-side API is returning you proper JSON response.

Comment: Thanks @MohammedGadi that seems to be the error, can you please read my update. So the solution is to tell backend to return a JSON or to change the JSON.parse() prototype? what do you think?

Comment: Got to your chrome nework tab and see the response by clicking on the url.

Comment: By the way are you using asp.net mvc as backend?

Comment: @MohammedGadi , backend guys are using Java. the response es an html: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian) - Error re...

Comment: check the header type in angularjs from below code.So if you are expecting json response and if you are getting HTML as the failed response you can show your custom message. So here is the code you can check that the header is of json type of HTML type:
`$http.get(myUrl)
.then(function(data) {
  const contentType = data.headers.get('Content-type');
 if (contentType == 'application/json') {
    return response.json();   
   } else if (contentType == 'application/text') {
    return response.text(); 
}, function(e) {
  console.log('err', e); //error prints undefined
});`

Comment: @MohammedGadi well yeah checking in chrome `network>headers` tab: Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8 then in response `subtab` of network I get an html response. So it seems this difference between header content type and actual response type is causing the error.

Comment: hey @MohammedGadi I found the answer thanks for your great help :) will upvote your input. The problem was I was closing a modal, and the function called on this close modal was replacing erronously the url and making it repeat.

Comment: Did you try to send a call to a third service, e.g. https://httpbin.org? Check if this works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your self.baseUrl should contain the host address(along with port number) also, else it will take the host address from where your application is getting hosted.
So please update your base address to contain complete address with host name.

Comment: So I modify it to:  `self.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/variants/'; ` now I get the same error but with localhost included: `http://localhost:8080/http://localhost:8080/variants/202http://localhost:8080/variants/http://localhost:8080/variants/215`

Comment: In my application i tested same thing and it works, please try this,
$http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
.then(function successCallback(response) {
   deferred.resolve(response.data);
});
This is get request which will send you your ip address check this in dev console in network tab in chrome browser, if your request response is correct, then update your own code by referencing this.